# Becoming much more fluent than what I am already am?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

I have just watched a video on how to improve my english communication skills. And a phrase caught my attention which says:

> ...''That is why I'm helping you guys becoming much more fluent **than your(or your're?) already are."**

What if I changed it into me as the speaker specifically:

> Becoming much more fluent **than what I'm already am.**

Is this correct? and there are 2 ''**am**" in a sentence? Oh man :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope that's not what he actually said. If he did, find a new teacher :)

> ..."That is why I'm helping you guys becoming much more fluent than your (or you're?) already are."

No. Horrible in many ways.

..."That is why I'm helping you guys **to become** much more fluent than **you** already are."

Much better.

That will probably make you immediately see your re-cast also cannot have "I'm" or 'becoming' either.

> "Become much more fluent than I already am."

Additionally removing 'what' might only be stylistic, but it flows much better without it.
Leaving 'what' in would remind anyone from the UK old enough to remember Morecambe & Wise - Ernie Wise & his intentionally badly worded ["Play what I wrote"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Play_What_I_Wrote), which was actually turned into a stage play, in tribute.

To re-cast it in much more simple terms, those a native would use without even thinking, I'd also either lose 'already' entirely, or replace it with 'currently'

So, my personal preferred versions, either

> "Become much more fluent than I currently am."

or

> "Become much more fluent than I am."

The last is succinct & to the point.

*Late thought* ...
In the teacher's example - once we've corrected it - leaving the word 'already' in there then becomes *encouragement*. He believes [& wants you to believe] that you are *already* fluent & just need guidance to improve still further.

If you refer to yourself in the same way, it could imply boasting.
Using 'currently' or nothing at all leaves out any impression of your own belief in your own skills.

Comment: Nice! Now I'm much better than I previously am hehe.

Comment: ... was :P "Now I'm much better than I previously was" ;)

Comment: Oh I see, I thought it was a fixed thing. Anyway, got it.

Comment: 'Previously' pushes into past tense. I can become better than I **am**, but when I've done that I will be better than I **was** [back when I started]. Make sense?

Comment: Crystal clear. Cheers!